# How to extract Zip archive located under different user directory in ISPConfig 3

Tags: php, ispconfig

I face the problem with extracting the `.zip` archive located under different user `web/` directory. Let me  explain: I have 2 websites both written on pure php. `First` website i use to manage `Second`. Every client on `Second` website has his own folder located in `root` with similar code but different configs. It looks like this:

**Second website**

```
...
/var/www/clients/client0/web2/web/client1/...
/var/www/clients/client0/web2/web/client2/...
...
```

Like you understand owner of this files is user: `web2` and group: `client0`

**And First website location:**

```
...
/var/www/clients/client0/web1/web/...
...
```

Owner of this files is user: `web1` and group: `client0`

What I'm trying to do is to extract `zip` archive at Second webroot directory while working on my backend on First website when create a new client.

Here is the code i tried(this works perfect on my localhost when user: `www-data` and group: `www-data`):

```
...
if (!file_exists('/var/www/clients/client0/web2/web/' . $_POST['storeid'])) {
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $dir = '/var/www/clients/client0/web2/web/';
    $install_dir = $dir . 'backup/';

    $res = $zip->open($install_dir . 'client_install.zip');

    if ($res === TRUE) {

        //Try to execute

        $zip->extractTo($dir . $_POST['storeid'] . '/'); //var/www/clients/client0/web2/client2

        $zip->close();

        //Set permitions on new store folder
        chmod_r($dir . $_POST['storeid'], 0755, 0644);

        echo "\nExtracted successfully to " . $dir;
        die();
    } else {
        echo "Failed to open zip: " . $dir . "client_install.zip" . " \n";
        die();
    }
}
...
```

At the time when i run this code i get message:

> Failed to open zip:
>   /var/www/clients/client0/web2/web/backup/client_install.zip

I know it may be related to user permissions. How can solve this considering keeping same ISPConfig environment and user permissions.

**Update:**

Here is the error log message:

> PHP Warning: ZipArchive::open(): open_basedir restriction in effect.
>   File(/var/www/clients/client0/web2/web/client1/backup/client_install.zip)
>   is not within the allowed path(s):(/var/www/clients/client0/web1/web:/var/www/clients/client0/web1/private:/var/www/clients/client0/web1/tmp:/var/www/test.site.com/web:/srv/www/test.site.com/web:/usr/share/php5:/usr/share/php:/tmp:/usr/share/phpmyadmin:/etc/phpmyadmin:/var/lib/phpmyadmin)
>   in /var/www/clients/client0/web1/web/process.php on line 261.

My question may sound stupid, so I'm sorry in advance. But can a change in the entry in a particular website of `open_basedir` option affect the performance of the entire server, or the inability of Apache to restart. My question is because my test website is located on a server with production sites. And I would not want to make these changes without initial consultation. So I think I need to add a new path to the `open_basedir` site parameter. People who know how this option works specifically, please respond to this post. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's the message you've written. It illustrates that `$res` is not `true`. What is it then?

Comment: `$res` return `bool(false)`, and no any other info.

Comment: Not even an error code. That's weird. Do you have access to full error reporting messages? Some times when random file system functions fail you get a warning with some info.

Comment: I will check on the server apache log right now, but i also check `if (!file_exists(...` that means that php worker has access to this directory correct? or `file_exist` return false even if it does not have the rights to check?

Comment: Apache error log is clear.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I got some updates, can you check?

Comment: `open_basedir` is not an optimisation of any kind. It's a last resort security mechanism for shared hosting that doesn't apply restrictions on OS level. And it seems it's working nicely in your case :)